# Nginx problem with .min.css and .min.js files

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I Have ubuntu VPS with nginx installed on it , nginx has problem with **.min.css** and **.min.js** files and instead renders empty html file.
what is the problem ?

thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing any vendor files directly. They shouldn't even be in the public folder.

Comment: @aynber its not my fault dude :) , some laravel packages have their own vendor files like laravel unisharp file manager or ... ! all other vendor files are accessible but , this directory return nothing ! the amazing part is nothing

Comment: Try restarting the server. Also check if git pulled everything.

Comment: @abdulla_malik I restarted the server , and everything is pulled ! I checked , I'm getting crazy :|

Comment: The amazing part is its just with one folder !!

Comment: can you gives much more information ? which files ? which packages ? gives any error ? did you checked laravel.log ?

Comment: Can you give us the path where your webserver root is ? and the path of the concerned folder ?

Comment: Sometimes the issue can be permission. use chmod 755 on the folder

Comment: There may not be anything *to* output. If you look at the code itself, it's probably just a class that returns data to another script. There may not be any code to actually output anything to the screen. But without more data, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED : 
First , I have to say , when I said it is amazing for me, because I am familiar with nginx and server blocks , file permissions , directory calling , console checking , and ... all other error checking systems ! so everything was ok.
I do not know why that happened ! but problem was exactly as I said ! just .min.css and .min.js files have problem with loading ! even with direct access to public folder with 777 permission the problem was there again ! but one thing solved the problem for me , deleting nginx access log and error log files from my directory ! 
now everything is ok !
I do not know why ! but it works.

Thanks To All

Comment: Probably it works now, cause you didn't restart nginx after proper changes, or you are running out of space and deleting logs did help you for a moment...

Comment: @Bart :)) , I'm not that beginner.